# Goal Programming in Cplex

Tags: java, optimization, linear-programming, cplex

Let's say I have the two goals. I want to reach that goals really close:

```
i=1) profit goal: 12 + 9y ≥ 125
i=2) cost-goal: 5 + 7y ≤ 50
```

In the literature you can do goal-programming by inserting variables, which represent deviations. Let's say the variable *ai* is the deviation above the goal value from goal I and *bi* is the deviation below the goal value from goal I. You get the following constraints:

```
12 + 9y -a1 + b1 = 125
5 + 7y -a2 + b2 = 50
```

In the last step you create the objective function, where you can punish the deviations with a punish-factor (p) for each deviation.

```
minimize: pd1*b1 + pa1*a1 + pd2*b2 + pa2*a2
```

I'm working with the Cplex API and I saw, that you can work with Cplex-Goals:

```
IloCplex.Goal
```

Now I have the following questions:

1. Is there a possibility to get this problem solved with Cplex API in a handy way or do I have to implement this procedure by myself?
2. If it is possible, how do I get the resulting goal-values: 12 + 9y and 5 + 7y?

Comment: Cplex goals are for controlling the branching and are not related to goal programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible using CPLEX. In fact, you have already done most of the formulation that is needed, by introducing a1, a2, b1 and b2. Now, you just need to create a Cplex model object, give it the objective and solve it. (You don't need `IloCplex.Goal`) Just solve a straight LP.

Take a look at any of these Java [examples](http://eaton.math.rpi.edu/cplex90html/usrcplex/solveQP10.html) and follow them as a template.

Just set your objective function. (pa0, pb1 etc. are constants)

```
 IloNumExpr obj = cplex.sum(cplex.prod(pa0, a[0]), 
                             cplex.prod(pa1, a[1]),
                             cplex.prod(pb0, b[0]),
                             cplex.prod(pb1, b[1])); 

    model.add(IloMinimize(env, obj));
```

Then, have CPLEX solve your LP, you can simply get the optimal values of a[0], a[1],b[0] and b[1] to see the deviations from the Goals. (Note that only one of a or b will be positive.) Use `cplex.getValues(x)` to query the variable values.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Like this: 
    // decision variable
    dvar int x;
    dvar int y;

```
//obj function 
IloNumExpr obj = cplex.sum(cplex.prod(pa0, a[0]), 
                             cplex.prod(pa1, a[1]),
                             cplex.prod(pb0, b[0]),
                             cplex.prod(pb1, b[1])); 
       model.add(IloMinimize(env, obj));

// constraints
subject to {

12* x + 9*y -a1 + b1 <= 125;
5* x + 7*y -a2 +b2 <= 50;

}
```

But actually is not working. Help please! =)